# mount.cifs for mounting NAS unit not working on 17.10

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

This worked fine on 17.04:

```
sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=myname,password=mypassword //nas/share /mnt/nas
```

Now on 17.10 it gives me:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.150,unc=\\nas\share,user=myname,pass=********
mount error(95): Operation not supported
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

A singularly unhelpful error message, given that the manpage hasn't changed. I can't figure out how to increase the verbosity of the error message beyond the above. How do I persuade mount.cifs to tell me what it doesn't like?

Comment: Don't mix question and answer, so it may confound someone looks for a full-reported solution to this issue. You must separate question and answer, each one in appropriate section.

Answer (score 5):

Never mind. Solved.

"cifs troubleshooting" turned out to be the magic words for Google, rather than "mount verbosity" etc.

```
# modprobe cifs
# echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI
# mount... etc.
# dmesg
```

Gave me:

```
CIFS VFS: Dialect not supported by server. Consider specifying
vers=1.0 or vers=2.1 on mount for accessing older servers
```

And adding "vers=2.1" to the options fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

After doing a modprobe / dmesg, I got this message:

> No dialect specified on mount. Default has changed to a more secure
>   dialect, SMB2.1 or later (e.g. SMB3), from CIFS (SMB1). To use the
>   less secure SMB1 dialect to access old servers which do not support
>   SMB3 (or SMB2.1) specify vers=1.0 on mount.

Thus it worked adding the "vers=1.0" to the options.